# How can I set the current working directory for docker exec with an internal bash shell?

Tags: bash, docker

I have a developer docker image based on ubuntu:14.04 that I use to develop apps for Ubuntu 14.04.  I start this image when the machine boots with `docker start image-name`

My home directory was bind mounted with --volumes when initially created.

To enter the image I have an alias defined in `.bash_aliases`

```
alias d_enter="docker exec -ti ub1404-dev /bin/bash"
```

So to enter the image I just type `d_enter`

But I often forget to run d_enter after entering a long path and would like d_enter to switch to that internal directory automatically.

The following doesn't work.

```
docker exec -ti ub1404-dev /bin/bash <(echo ". ~/.bashrc && cd $(pwd)")
```

Is there another way I could achieve the desired result?

For example, if my current working directory is: `/home/matt/dev/somepath/blabla`

And I type d_enter, my current working directory currently becomes: `/home/matt` what I want to do for current directory after exec is be `/home/matt/dev/somepath/blabla`

Comment: It sure is frustrating when people downvote without leaving a comment.  If there is something you don't understand, please say so and I'll improve the question.  Questions similar to bash subshell issues like this exist and it's a common problem.  I've tried to follow the suggested answers but they don't seem to work in my case.  I'd like to understand why that is

Comment: can you please elaborate more on your question? there are literally many parameters and I can answer all of them, but for the sake of specificity I need you to enhance your question. with a fully working example. like what do you want to do after cd-ing into that dir? etc..

Comment: @M03 - no the question is too old and has an adequate answer.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

From API 1.35+ you can use the `-w` (`--workdir`) option:

```
docker exec -w /my/dir container_name command
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: Old question but I think this would work best.  I could "docker -exec `pwd` d_enter"

Answer (score 25):

You can achieve it with:
`docker exec -it containerName sh -c "cd /var/www && /bin/bash"`

Comment: Great solution if you are not on API 1.35+

Comment: Yeas! Used it with docker-compose

Answer (score 7):

When building an image, one can specify the [WORKDIR variable](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) in `Dockerfile`:

```
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

Comment: When I use this variable, the system still starts in a directory named "tf", which I never defined anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely a hack but you could do something like making `d_enter` a shell function (could stay an alias but this is easier to maintain):

```
d_enter() {
  pwd > ~/.docker_initial_pwd
  docker exec -ti ub1404-dev /bin/bash
}
```

And then in the container in your user account's `.bashrc`, add something like:

```
if [[ -f "${HOME}/.docker_initial_pwd ]]; then
  cd $(cat "${HOME}/.docker_initial_pwd")
fi
```